# Twig simple overriding with include

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a simple Twig template, were I wan to override a block from the  include.

`base.html.twig`:

```
{% block razem %}
    {% include '_ga.code.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

`_ga.code.html.twig`:

```
{% block wspolny %}
    should be common
{% endblock %}

{% block googleAnalitics %}
    for overridden
{% endblock %}
```

`success.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'base.hmtl.twig' %}

{% block razem %}
    {{ parent('wspolny') }}

    {% block googleAnalitics %}
        overriding part
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Where is the error? http://twigfiddle.com/jsuk6a

I expected to render something like this:

```
should be common
overriding part
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you please write more about your problem? Your question is not very clear like this.

Comment: I think the error is in 'extends'. It states 'base.twig' instead of 'base.html.twig'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In twig you can not override blocks in a include. For this you have to use embed, but have to do this in the using template, not in the base one.

`base.html.twig`:

```
{% block razem %}{% endblock %}
```

`_ga.code.html.twig`:

```
{% block wspolny %}
    should be common
{% endblock %}

{% block googleAnalitics %}
    for overridden
{% endblock %}
```

`success.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'base.hmtl.twig' %}

{% block razem %}
    {% embed '_ga.code.html.twig' %}
        {% block googleAnalitics %}
            overriding part
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best way to *override* a block and reuse some others is to extend the base template where you want to perform an overriding (maybe adding some code to the pre-existing one) and to apply the so called [*horizontal reuse*](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html):

> Horizontal reuse is an advanced Twig feature that is hardly ever needed in regular templates. It is mainly used by projects that need to make template blocks reusable without using inheritance.

Starting from that point, you should simply use the `base.html.twig` template and extend `_ga.code.html.twig` as follows:

<kbd>**success.html.twig**</kbd>

```
{% extends '_ga.code.hmtl.twig' %}
{# Simply use base - without overriding #}
{% use 'base.hmtl.twig' %}

    {% block googleAnalitics %}
        overriding part
    {% endblock %}
```

If you want to make an *overload* of a single block you could also use the `parent()` function; so, you can add some other information to an extended block.

If you need something more complex you should go for [dynamic inheritance](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#dynamic-inheritance).

```
{% extends ['base.html.twig', '_ga.code.html.twig'] %}
```